# Can´t add new App via my App Community page. there is no link at all

Tags: facebook, tabs

Created a new App, created a new Fanpage for this App but if i click on "view my app profile page" it says that this page was not found. Other strange thing, if i click the link in the modal window where it says "The #NameOfMyApp Community page has been created and connected with this app." I´ll be redirected to my App Community page but there is no link where can add this app to my main Page. I´ve done this several times with several apps for the last few months, always the same way - worked like a charm. What´s wrong now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is temporarily "broken". Facebook has removed profile pages from new apps and replaced it with a add to page widget which is not yet available unless you manually install it somewhere. Very unintutive, but perhaps this will help: http://www.addtab.info/